# for loops for removing row names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a series of data frames of the following format:

```
Q1_output
Q2_output
```

all the way to:

```
QN_output
```

I would like to reset the row names to null for all data frames in such a list. Is there a for loop I can write that will accomplish the

```
 rownames(Q1_output) <- NULL
```

Precisely what the "N" is will vary, so I can alter that in the loop each time.

Thank you!

Comment: `lapply` on the list `lapply(list, function(i) rownames(i) <- NULL; i)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the row names to be like 1 to n, being n the number of rows, you have to have the data frames stored in a list. You cannot set the rows name to be all null since they have to be unique

```
for i in (1:n)
   rownames(data_frame_list[i])<-NULL
```

This will set your data frames to have the rownames from 1 to number of rows